# Insert Into add double record MySQL Statment

Tags: mysql, tomcat, intellij-idea, insert-into

In IntelliJ I'm trying to add new record to MySQL table, but, when I start server (Tomcat 9.0.141) it add double record. When I refresh browser it adding only once and when I start server (Tomcat) it adding two times. I have looking for answer everywhere, even in group on FB, and nobody know what to say. pls help. Here is my whole servlet:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/sqlu")
public class MySQLServletUpdate extends HttpServlet {


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    try{
        Driver driver = new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AppJEE?useSSL=false&characterEncoding=utf8&useJDBCCompianttimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimecode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "password");

        PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?)");
        pstmt.setString(1, "Mark");
        pstmt.setString(2, "Marks");
        pstmt.setString(3, "Mar");

        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0) {
            response.getWriter().println("Record added");
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is some errors that appear when i look at table in phpMyAdmin:

```
    Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'AppJEE',
string 'uzytkownik',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `uzytkownik`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'AppJEE',
string 'uzytkownik',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `uzytkownik`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./index.php#53: include(./sql.php)
```

Here is one view on my table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvox0.png)

Here is another view on my table[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knyiR.png)

Comment: Could you share the table where you add and the end result?

Comment: Table view added

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my case by setting Tomcat server run only without loading page immediately. When Tomcat run, I manual go to browser and loading page, and then it add record only once.